# Why is this not recognized anymore "The name 'ScreenshotImageFormat' does not exist in the current context"?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have the following program that I run every month on some website pages (you know Selenium testing etc.) and then I upload the output screenshots somewhere.

For some reason, suddenly this time the program threw this error and prompted me to run the last successful build from previous month. I chose that and got the screenshots as I wanted but I don't want to use last successful build every time, why is this error being thrown suddenly now when no code changes have been done?

```
Error   CS0103  The name 'ScreenshotImageFormat' does not exist in the current context
```

program.cs

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;

namespace SSL_Labs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] domains;

            // TODO: Config
            domains = new string[] { "website1.com", "website2.com"};

            foreach (string d in domains) { 
                GenerateSslLabsReport(d);
            }
        }
        
        private static void GenerateSslLabsReport(string domain)
        {
            IWebDriver driver;
            IWebElement hostName;
            IWebElement hideResults;
            IWebElement submit;
            WebDriverWait waitForReport;
            ITakesScreenshot screenshot;

            string outputBasePath = "C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\SSL\\";
            string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM");
            string subDirectory = "Output_" + timestamp;
            string outputPath = Path.Combine(outputBasePath, subDirectory) + "\\";
            Directory.CreateDirectory(outputPath);
            string createdDirectoryPath = outputPath;

            /* Uncomment below code if you want to test directory path is correct
            string fileName = "sample.txt";
            string filePath = Path.Combine(createdDirectoryPath, fileName);
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, "This is a sample text file.");

            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File created successfully.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File not created.");
            }
            */

            Console.WriteLine("Starting SSL Labs reporting ...");

            driver = null;

            try
            {
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                driver.Url = "https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/";

                hideResults = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='hideResults']"));
                hideResults.Click();

                hostName = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@name='d']"));
                hostName.SendKeys(domain);
                
                submit = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@type='submit']"));
                submit.Click();

                waitForReport = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 120));
                waitForReport.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//*[@id='rating']")));

                // TODO: Config
                File.WriteAllText(string.Format(createdDirectoryPath + "{0}.html", domain), driver.PageSource.Replace("<head>", "<head><base href=\"https://www.ssllabs.com/\" target=\"_blank\"></base"));

                screenshot = (ITakesScreenshot)driver;
            
                screenshot.GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile(string.Format(createdDirectoryPath + "{0}.png", domain), ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);

                driver.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error processing domain: {domain}");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (driver != null) driver.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing I did was update the Selenium drivers as I usually do every month, so that it doesn't conflict with the new Chrome updates.

[image: updated drivers]

Comment: Did it move to a different namespace? Is it documented to having been deprecated and what to use instead?

Comment: Since that enum duplicates functionality in .NET already, they may have removed it.  Try adding `using System.Drawing;` and `using System.Drawing.Imaging;` at the top.

Comment: @TimRoberts doesnt help, still same error

Comment: @Fildor i tried searching online about it to see if that is the case (i suspected its been deprecated) but couldnt find anything about it. It doesnt say anything in Visual Studio besides the error i posted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not to pass ScreenshotImageFormat.Png

I mean
`screenshot.GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile(string.Format(createdDirectoryPath + "{0}.png", domain));`

Comment: not that, but after removing 'ScreenshotImageFormat.Png' it worked.